# Temporarily disable 'set-e' / 'set -o errexit' in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a script that uses `killall` to make sure an app isn't already running before starting it:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

some_command
another_command

sudo killall myapp # this causes the script to fail if myapp isn't running
sleep 10
myapp start
```

However, if myapp isn't running, `killall` will exit the script because it returns an error.

One option to work around this is to temporarily disable `set -o errexit`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

some_command
another_command

set +e
sudo killall myapp # this causes the script to fail if myapp isn't running
set -e
sleep 10
myapp start
```

However, the above approach is quite messy.  What other options are there for temporarily disabling `set -e`?

Comment: There is no other way that I know of but if it's just for one command, you can instead ignore its exit code:

`some_command || true`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want just allow this single command to end with error and consider it normal you can:

```
sudo killall myapp || :
```

: is a noop in bash. Effectively the line above is as explicitly as possible expressing "on error do nothing". You can achieve the same effect with maybe a little more idiomatic:

```
sudo killall myapp || true
```

Of course you can also do something else like:

```
sudo killall myapp || echo "Failed to kill Myapp, probably it is not running at the moment." >&2
```